# Why won't my if() statement work? Javascript

Tags: javascript

I can't seem to figure out why this if() statement works, any ideas why?

```
Game.Items = {autoClickers: [50, 1, "Gives you one click every second, cost 50 clicks."]};
Game.UsersItems = {itemAutoClickers: [0], itemClickingTeam: [0]};

if(Game.UsersItems.itemAutoClickers > 0) {
    setInterval(function() {
         Game.Clicks = Game.Clicks + Game.Items.autoClickers[1];
         getElement('clicks').innerText = "Clicks: "+Game.Clicks;
         document.title = "Pointer Clicker | Clicks: "+Game.Clicks;
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: `0` isn't greater than `0`

Comment: It get's updates after they buy one, so this will check if it is.

Comment: But is the `if` statement running again after they buy one? The way your code reads, it'll always be `0`.

Comment: Sorry, I will delete the question, quite a silly mistake, I've fixed it. :0

Comment: You won't be able to delete.  I'll flag it as off topic.

Comment: @cookiemonster I figured it out. I want to delete the question but I can't any ideas? Will not use points?

Comment: Flag it as off topic since the issue wasn't represented in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Game.UserItems.itemAutoClickers is an array is it its `.length` you want to check?

or is it the value of the first index of your array?

`Game.UserItems.itemAutoClickers[0]` in that case

Comment: Questions asking for clarification should be posted in a comment. And accessing the `0` index won't change the result.

Answer (score 2):

are you trying to check if the number of items in `itemAutoClickers` array is greater than 0 or if the value of the first item is greater than 0?

`Game.UsersItems.itemAutoClickers.length > 0`

or

`Game.UsersItems.itemAutoClickers[0] > 0`

Comment: The value of itemAutoClickers is greater than 0.

Comment: Hey, sorry but this should be a comment